# How do I fix this Rubik's cube

Tags: rubiks-cube

I finished the cube but got this on 1 side:

[image]

How do I fix it without ruining it?

It is fixable, I did it once but I don't know how I did it.

Comment: This isn't really a puzzle. However, most Rubik's cubes allow you to take out the middle piece and put it back in so you can tighten/loosen the cube.

Comment: Check out this page for rotating center pieces. http://www.alchemistmatt.com/cube/rubikcenter.html

Comment: What I usually do is hold the cube with the center that has to be rotated 180 degrees at the top, and then use: `R U R' U (5x)`. Jaap's algorithm seems to be shorter though, and actually has reasoning why it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hold the cube so that the centre to be twisted is in the U face.
Then do the 12-move sequence:

R L U2 R' L' U

R L U2 R' L' U

What the first 5 moves do is to swap two opposite corners and two opposite edge of the U face. After a U quarter turn the moves are repeated to swap the other corner pair and edge pair. This means all the U layer pieces have been rotated 180 degrees around relative to the centre. When the U layer is then turned to its correct location it is only the centre that has twisted 180 degrees.